# What official sequels have there been to the 1939 Wizard of Oz movie?

Tags: sequels, the-wizard-of-oz

What official sequels have there been to the famous 1939 MGM movie *The Wizard of Oz*?  There have been tons of movies and TV shows based on L. Frank Baum's book *The Wonderful Wizard of Oz*, most recently the NBC show *Emerald City* (which is really bad by the way).

Wikipedia claims that the 1972 animated movie *[Journey Back to Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_Back_to_Oz)* is an official sequel, but is that right?  Are there any others?  Note that I'm specifically interested in movies or TV shows authorized by MGM.

Comment: [*Return to Oz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Oz) is a noteworthy *unofficial* sequel.

Comment: @faintsignal Yeah, there are lot of unofficial sequels and prequels.  A recent one is [*Oz: The Great and Powerful*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_the_Great_and_Powerful), which has a lot of references to the 1939 movie despite not being authorized by MGM.

Answer (score 3):

[*Return to Oz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Oz) (1985) was made by Walt Disney but never got the attention of the first movie.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notable in that it drew from material in Baum's later Oz books. It's a purely personal criterion, but that feels more "official" than the MGM imprimatur.

Comment: Do we really need 57 huge *moving* images in that? Are there any specific issues you're highlighting with these? In that case, feel free to point them out in the question, too. Or is this just supposed to work as a scrollable trailer?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I wish I could put the whole movie on here to view. I have removed some of the gifs.

Answer (score -2):

The only sequel I know of is The Wiz, with Michael Jackson and Diana Ross.

Comment: The Wiz isn't a sequel to the 1939 film. It's a retelling of the book on which the film is based. - "*the film **reimagines** the classic 1900 children's novel The Wonderful Wizard of Oz by L. Frank Baum with an African-American cast.*"